# how order a vector of struct

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

im working with c++ and NS3 for my thesis.
so i'd like to sort a vector of struct with the stl function sort so i'll post my header file where my vector is situated and i'll explain what i'd like to do.

```
#include "ns3/net-device.h"
#include "ns3/object.h"
#include "ns3/log.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "miscellaneous.h"


namespace ns3 {

/**
 * \brief The UeRecord class is developed in order to store at the eNodeB
 * all information (such as feedback cqi, mac address etc...) of a UE registered
 * into that eNodeB. All UE records are managed by the UeManager class
 */
class UeRecord : public Object
{
public:
  UeRecord ();
  ~UeRecord ();

  /**
   * \brief CqiFeedbacks represents a list of CQI feedbacks
   * sent by the UE. The downlink packet scheduler of
   * the eNB uses these values to assign accordingly
   * radio resources.
   */


  /**
   * \brief a list of CQI feedbacks
   */
  typedef std::vector<struct CqiFeedback> CqiFeedbacks;


  /**
   * \brief Creates a ue record of the UE registered into the eNB
   * \param ue the pointer of the ue device
   * \param enb the pointer of the enb device
   */
  UeRecord (Ptr<NetDevice> ue, Ptr<NetDevice> enb);

  /**
   * \brief Set the UE of the record
   * \param ue the pointer of the ue device
   */
  void SetUe (Ptr<NetDevice> ue);

  /**
   * \brief Get the UE of the record
   * \returns the pointer of the UE
   */
  Ptr<NetDevice> GetUe (void);

  /**
   * \brief Set the eNB of the record
   * \param enb the pointer of the enb device
   */
  void SetEnb (Ptr<NetDevice> enb);

  /**
   * \brief Get the eNB of the record
   * \returns the pointer of the eNB
   */
  Ptr<NetDevice> GetEnb (void);


  /**
   * \brief Set CQI feedbacks of the registered UE
   * \param cqiFeedbacks a list of CQI feedback
   */
  void SetCqiFeedbacks (CqiFeedbacks cqiFeedbacks);

  /**
   * \brief Get CQI feedbacks of the registered UE
   * \returns a list of CQI feedback
   */
  CqiFeedbacks GetCqiFeedbacks (void);


public:
      friend bool operator > (const struct CqiFeedback &a, const struct CqiFeedback &b);

    inline bool operator > (const struct CqiFeedback &a, const struct CqiFeedback &b)
  {
      if(a.m_cqi>b.mcqi) return true;
        return false;
   }

private:
  Ptr<NetDevice> m_ue;
  Ptr<NetDevice> m_enb;
  CqiFeedbacks m_cqiFeedbacks;

};
```

the struct is this

```
struct CqiFeedback
  {
    /** the sub channel */
    int m_subChannelId;
    /** the cqi feedback */
    int m_cqi;
  };
```

i'd like to sort in descending order the vector m_cqiFeedbacks by the m_cqi parameter,
the struct contained inside the header file miscellaneous.h.
so i tried to overload the operator > in the previous way but i got this error:

```
debug/ns3/ue-record.h:121: error: ‘bool ns3::UeRecord::operator>(const CqiFeedback&, const CqiFeedback&)’ must take exactly one argument
```

i don't understand what is wrong!!
may you help me please, i tried to read previous discussion, but i didn't realize very well what the problem is ....

Comment: "Waiter, one vector of structs please!"

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you can just `return a.m_cqi>b.mcqi;` in your comparison function.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
friend bool operator > (const struct CqiFeedback &a, const struct CqiFeedback &b);

inline bool operator > (const struct CqiFeedback &a, const struct CqiFeedback &b)
{
  if(a.m_cqi>b.mcqi) return true;
    return false;
}
```

should be

```
friend bool operator > (const struct CqiFeedback &a, const struct CqiFeedback &b)
{
  if(a.m_cqi>b.mcqi) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Declaring an operator as `friend` inside a class lets you implement as a free operator - in this case taking 2 explicit parameters. So you've declared the free operator, okay, but then you declare the member operator as `inline` with 2 parameters, plus the implicit `this`, so 3 total parameters, which is wrong.

Alternatively, if you want a member operator, do:

```
inline bool operator > (const struct CqiFeedback &b) const
{
  if( m_cqi>b.mcqi ) return true;
    return false;
}
```

And, of course, you can replace

```
  if( m_cqi>b.mcqi ) return true;
    return false;
```

with a simple

```
  return m_cqi > b.mcqi
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea.  If `CqiFeedback` has a universally agreed upon ordering (like `int`), so that anyone looking at `lhs_cqi < rhs_cqi` understands intuitively what is meant, fine.  (But in that case, don't forget `>`, `<=` and `>=` as well.)  Otherwise, just define an ordering functional object, and pass that to `std::sort`.  There's no need for operator overloading abuse just to use `std::sort`.

Comment: thank you for the answers, i tried to solve it with the greater function of stl.